# How to make dynamic website searchable by search engine

Tags: java, ajax, gwt

I have developed dynamic website using technology like ajax,java etc, that is constantly generating new pages with ID(like http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1419242644475) similarly like stackoverflow.com, but my sites pages is not searchable by google or any other search engine.

I want my pages show in the search result searched by search engine. How can I achieve this? I have not submitted any sitemap to google webmaster tool. is sitemap really a right solution...??? that means we have to regenerate the sitemap eachtime(or at set interval) when some one add a question on my website.
I m really very confused that how searche ngine search dynamically created pages like stackoverflow question and facebook proile.

Comment: This is due to # used in the URL.

Comment: thanks dear. but if i post complete link(like http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1419242644475) on google search still not showing any result.

Answer (score 1):

Look up how `meta tags` works. Every dynamic page will have its own set tags and description.

Also it takes time for Google to index your pages. 
Another reason why your website isn't shown in the results is because your key words are too common. Google indexes websites based on keywords mentioned in the meta tags. If they are very common, there will be other popular sites that are ranked above yours. Hence your site is not on the top results. 
Google also takes into consideration the popularity of your website. It calls this `juice`. Your website juice increases and decreases based on how old your site is, and how many relevant redirections happen to and from your website.

All the points I mentioned are just a few things that come under the heading `search engine optimization`. 
SEO is a massive concept and you will only learn it eventually as your website grows.

On the other hand, if you want Google to push your results up to the top. You can pay Google to do so. Google has the biggest advertising business.

Comment: thanks dear. but if i paste complete link on google search, still not showing any result.

Comment: Like I said, Google doesn't search with url. It searches with keywords. Give it some time, with continued use, it'll probably show up. But if you want to fasten the process, then submit your link to the webmaster, and make social profiles/pages. Social networks help a lot in SEO. sometimes your social page will rank over your website. But that's only initially :)

Comment: And you don't have to resubmit the site map every time  a new question is created. Webmaster handles them nicely, but do have individual meta tags for each question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because search engines can not find URLs containing /#?= . So you can rewrite you URLs. This page can help you to do this. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Answer (score -1):

First of all, to be indexed by Google, first Google should FIND the url. Best way to be found is to have many backlinks(popularity). other wise you have to submit sitemap or URL to search engines.

Unfortunately the query "inurl:#!" giving zero results in Google. So Luiggi Mendoza is right about it.

You can try rewrite URLS using htaccess to make them SEO friendly.